# How to move file from secondary harddisk to directory in home directory?

Tags: permissions, hard-drive

For a friend I finally got ubuntu running on sdd, version 22.04.
When trying to move a file from harddisk to sdd i get an error:

```
mv: cannot remove 'temp.kop': Read-only file system
```

Copying works fine.
Just recently I managed to get ubuntu installed on a newly created partition on sdd.
Not sure íf relevant but windows still lives on sdd as well (*sudo fdisk -l*, looked for */dev/sd*):

```
/dev/sdb1            2048 104859647 104857600  50G  7 HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
```

That will need to stay there, for now.

**Harddisk** partition with data to be used is mounted:

```
/dev/sda2 on **/media/hansl/Data** type fuseblk (ro,nosuid,nodev,relatime,user_id=0,group_id=0,default_permissions,allow_other,blksize=4096,uhelper=udisks2)
```

Mounted partitions on **sdd** for ubuntu (where under home destination dir resides):

```
/dev/sdb4 on / type ext4 (rw,relatime,errors=remount-ro)<br>
/dev/sdb2 on /boot/efi type vfat (rw,relatime,fmask=0077,dmask=0077,codepage=437,iocharset=iso8859-1,shortname=mixed,errors=remount-ro)
```

**File** to be moved, on harddisk, resides in */media/hansl/Data/Temp/20221115_ubuntu/dextop* and is called *temp.kop*.
So starting in home-dir *~* with these steps i can see the file:

```
cd /media/hansl/Data/Temp/20221115_ubuntu/dextop<br>
```

ls -la temp.kop

It shows:

```
-rwxrwxrwx 1 hansl hansl 5231 nov 18 13:58 temp.kop
```

**Destination** is Desktop directory. With this command it is shown

```
ls -la ~/Desktop<br>
total 16<br>
drwxr-xr-x  2 hansl hansl 4096 nov 20 17:55 .<br>
drwxr-x--- 19 hansl hansl 4096 nov 20 17:50 ..<br>
-rwxrwxrwx  1 hansl hansl 5231 nov 17 14:32 file.tmp<br>
lrwxrwxrwx  1 hansl hansl   21 nov 20 16:20 Temp.tmp -> ../Documents/temp.tmp
```

The above error is shown after this move command:

```
mv temp.kop ~/Desktop/
```

The command from within the Desktop dir gives the same error:

```
mv: cannot remove '/media/hansl/Data/Temp/20221115_ubuntu/dextop/temp.kop': Read-only file system
```

How can I make sure files can be moved from harddisk to sdd, in the way described above?

Comment: The options you’ve included for `/dev/sda2` has `ro`, which means “read only”. You cannot remove files while read only as a delete is technically a write. You will need to use `rw` at the very least.

Comment: Okay, thanx.


So although the file itself has `-rwxrwxrwx` files cannot be moved, or deleted, because the partition has `ro`, right?
Is `rw` now automatically set  for `/dev/sda2/`, when partition is mounted (when i open it with *Files*)?
Or better yet, how do is set it myself?

Comment: Did windows shut down completely (ie not hibernate, fast start up disabled)? Windows not shutting down completely can cause file systems to mount read only.

Comment: We have just checked windows, fast startup is now disabled and windows is/was shutdown completely.
We used F11 to get to boot menu and chose the option that started windows (when installing ubuntu it was not aimed at having dual boot, ubuntu + windows, but just ubuntu).
Now, after switching pc off and on again, it automatically starts up windows. With F11 the other options (sata1-3, ubuntu 2x, UEFI OS) were tried but starting up ubuntu seems no longer possible.
We can use ubuntu live usb, but don't know how to prevent windows from starting up or how to make ubuntu startup.

Comment: Yes, this is a different question all together. <br>I will post a new question.