# Dual boot, ubuntu no longer starts up

Tags: boot, dual-boot

For previous question ([How to move file from secondary harddisk to directory in home directory?](https://askubuntu.com/q/1441719/1551076)) we managed to start windows(8) on dual boot desktop pc.

In windows "fast startup" was switched off and windows was shut down (not into hibernation).

Since then pc does no longer starts up ubuntu, only windows is started.

- Before attempt to start  up windows, (only) starting up ubuntu worked fine;
- Ubuntu (22.04) was installed on SSD that already holds windows (user data resides on 1.8 tb hard disk);
- Ubuntu was installed into a separate, new partition;
- Ubuntu was not installed 'along' windows (aim was to only start ubuntu, not have dual boot options menu);
- When starting up bios settings and dual boot menu (?) can be invoked (with F11 or some other function key). In the boot menu 2 ubuntu options exist. Choosing either of them makes the bios window flash 2 or 3 times after which windows is started;
- With `powercfg /h off` hibernate option was removed;
- Could not find Secure boot in bios settings;
- Bios has modes 'UEFI' and 'UEFI/Legacy', either one makes windows startup;
- Started up with ubuntu live usb and with Disks these details were shown:
- 240 gb disk (MBR):

  - filesystem, partition 1, 54 gb (23 gb free), NTFS, mounted.

    /dev/sdb1

    NTFS/exFAT/HPFS

    So: this is the **windows partition**;
  - filesystem, partition 2, 1,1 gb, not mounted.

    /dev/sdb2

    EFI (FAT-12/16/32) (bootable)
  - swap, partition 3, 27 gb, Active.

    /dev/sdb3

    Linux swap
  - filesystem, partition 4, 54 gb (35 gb free), Ext4, mounted.

    /dev/sdb4

    Linux

    So: this is the **ubuntu partition**;
  - Free space;
- Setting the sdb4 partition to bootable did not make ubuntu startup;
- `bcdedit /set {bootmgr} path \EFI\ubuntu\shimx64.efi` did not make ubuntu startup.

  Will try with double quotes and report back here: `bcdedit /set "{bootmgr}" path \EFI\ubuntu\grubx64.efi`.

What steps do we  need to take to get ubuntu to startup again?

There is a screenprint of windows diskmanagement (somewhat similar info as of Disks). If needed how do we post that here?

Comment: ```bcdedit /set "{bootmgr}" path \EFI\ubuntu\grubx64.efi``` did not seem to work. In boot menu ubuntu option (first one in list) was chosen. Window flashed several times and windows started up.

Comment: Rather than manually type data, post the link this gives. Please copy & paste the pastebin link to the BootInfo summary report ( do not post report), do not run the auto fix till reviewed. Use often updated ppa version over somewhat older ISO with your USB installer  or any working install.
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair & 
https://sourceforge.net/p/boot-repair/home/Home/

Comment: Not sure if this will help, but when I first installed a dual-boot system on a computer using UEFI, I had to change - in the bios menu - "SATA operation mode" from Optane Without RAID to AHCI. I think I had a similar issue to yours before I did this. BUT, it's not enough to just toggle that option in bios; there is also a procedure that must be done within Windows (which I can post here if that turns out to be your problem).

Comment: Thanx @oldfred ! I've used an existing live usb (intenso) to add and install boot-repair repo. Too much to type ;-) so here is the pastebin link: https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/BxsHpDCsXZ/. Did no rePair, just rePort.

Comment: You have new UEFI based hardware. That is because Microsoft has required vendors to install Windows in UEFI boot mode to gpt partitioned drives. But you have Windows in old BIOS/MBR configuration. Quick fix is to install grub in BIOS boot mode to sdb drive, keeping Windows BIOS boot on sda. Also make sure boot flag is on Windows boot partition. Grub does not use boot flag, UEFI also uses boot flag & that is why you cannot have UEFI & Windows BIOS boot on same drive.  Better to totally reinstall Windows in UEFI mode, but major backup & erase of drive required.

Comment: If data of sdb1 is still available, reachable then starting up windows is no longer needed. At some point windows can be removed all together.  So will need to install grub in bios mode on ssd (sdb). How to do that?

Comment: @oldfred Under Suggested repair, repair would purge + reinstall grub2 of sdb4 into the MBR of sdb. An additional repair is suggested. But "You may want to retry after changing it to BIOS-compatibility/CSM/Legacy mode." as well. Report finishes with "Please do not forget to make your BIOS boot on sdb (ATA KINGSTON SV300S3) disk!
Please set your BIOS in Legacy mode in order to start your Ubuntu ..., then type command [sudo update-grub] in order to add the Windows entry to your GRUB menu."       So would setting legacy mode in bios be the first next step? And then set booting on sdb (SSD)?

Comment: Each time you boot live installer, you can choose UEFI or BIOS boot. Most tools create flash drive that can be booted either way. But once installed, you have to have UEFI settings for default boot of installed system. It is better to use gpt parttioning whether UEFI or BIOS with Ubuntu. The only time you need MBR, is with Windows in BIOS boot mode.If new install now would be a good time to change. But MBR to gpt will erase drive. https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/Partitioning#Choosing_between_GPT_and_MBR UEFI installs want ESP - efi system partition on first drive.

Answer (score 0):

To be sure to solve this completely all partitions on SSD were unmounted or swapped off and then deleted using gparted (backup was made of relevant data).
Now ubuntu can be reinstalled on SSD.
Idea is to have a separate partition on SSD for ubuntu ( 100 gb, deleted sdb4 partition was 50gb ).
Will go over to ubuntu site to find installation instructions (again)
and íf other, separate partition(s) is/are needed.
sdb3 was swap partition (25 gb) and it seemed to have been used.